How to test a simple php Application with autoloading in XAMPP
I followed the Routing, Controller, View Part1 - PHP MVC Framework from Scratch (The Codeholic) in Youtube. Basically it is a manually coded (no vendor) Application with views - layout mechanism. I want to test just a first version with routing from method (GET) and path (localhost:8080/app or localhost:8080/app/Contact.)
I installed xampp 8.2.. and followed this question: How to configure Apache Virtual Hosts on xampp (Windows)
Here are the last lines of my httpd-vhosts.conf
<Directory C:/Users/frede/phpStorm>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#this is the default address of XAMPP    
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/XAMPP/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

#this is the first vhost address in XAMPP
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/frede/phpStorm/php-mvc-framework-own"
    ServerName php.localhost
    SetEnv NS_ENV variable_value
</VirtualHost>

Then I set my hosts in windows/system32/driver/etc
#127.0.0.1 mvc-tutorial.localhost localhost
127.0.0.1 app.localhost localhost
## Local - End #

Here is what I get in the browser after starting the server in development mode inside the root of my application
php -S localhost:8080 .
url http://localhost:8080/app
Warning: Unknown: Failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
Fatal error: Failed opening required '.' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0
Updated the namespace of my .php classes :
from  app\core to PhpMvcFrameworkOwn\core
php-mvc-framework-own is the name of my project directory, where I typed from Command powershell:
php composer.phar init
Here is the output of the composer.json file
{
    "name": "frede/php-mvc-framework-own",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Frede\\PhpMvcFrameworkOwn\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Frederic"
        }
    ],
    "require": {}
}

I got the error quoted above. Exected was at least one of the customized message from my application (eg "not found")
I did not managed to run anything what could lend me to a good direction? I have not inserted the code above since it should not be the cause, I saw the demo in the youtube tutorial.
(I have only experience in very simple forms php from OpenClassRoom, then I am interested in that (Codeholic) tutorial as an introduction for describing framework in an education project.)
